# intellij の embedded terminal にて PATH を設定するには？

Tags: windows, intellij-idea

IntelliJ IDEA 15 CE を利用しはじめている者です。

Alt+F12 で埋め込み terminal 画面を開くことができますが、このターミナルでPATHを設定する方法がわからずにいます。 Windows で開発していますが、普通に開いた場合のコマンドプロンプト自体の PATH を変えたいわけではなく、この埋め込み terminal で開いた場合の PATH を独自に設定したいと考えています。

これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

terminal内で下記のコマンドを実行すれば任意のパスに変更できます。

```
C:\IdeaProjects\hoge>set PATH="設定したいパス"
```

また、terminalを開いた時点で設定させておきたいのであれば、
File -> Settings... -> Tools -> Terminal を開き、
Shell pathに下記のように設定することでも可能です。

```
cmd.exe /k "set PATH=hoge"
```